# how to use is_admin in wp-config.php

Tags: wp-config

I am trying to choose different databases for admin and user to decrease the load on database.
in wp-config.php when i am trying to use the code

```
if(is_admin())
{
define('DB_NAME', 'wp_db');
}
else
{
define('DB_NAME', 'other_wp_db');
}
```

both databases uses same user name and password.

I am getting an error of

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function is_admin() in D:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-config.php on line 24

How to use is_admin() function in the wp-config.php file?

can someone please help.

Answer (score 4):

I would be careful doing this, because you are assuming all your database modifications will only happen within the admin backend, but that might not always be the case. The `wp-cron` comes to mind, but there are also some plugins that use front-end writes. So you might get nasty sync problems with your two databases, using this method.

There are many things you can do before going the *master/slave* route:

- Check for example your logs, if there's anything strange going on there.
- Maybe it's a plugin that's giving you problems?
- Maybe you have a `WP_Query` that's not efficient?
- Maybe you can use the transients API?
- Maybe you can consider persistant object cache?
- There are many cache plugins out there that can help.
- Maybe the hosting environment is slowing you down?
- Maybe the MySQL server isn't tuned well enough? Some helpful tuning scripts exists.
- Maybe it's time to update PHP, MySQL and start using NginX ;-)
- ...

If you decide this route is necessary, there are already solutions out there, like the *HyperDB* plugin, that gives you a `db.php` drop-in to be placed in the `wp-content` directory. It checks for any writes/updates in the incoming SQL queries and redirects them to the master database. But I just scanned through the [source](http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/hyperdb/trunk/db.php) and it looks like it's not supporting the `mysqli` extension, only the deprecated `mysql`. If you don't like forking this yourself, there seems to exists at least one [fork](https://github.com/soulseekah/hyperdb-mysqli) that supports `mysqli` (I'm not related to this project).

Answer (score 2):

It's too early to use this WP built-in function. You can use it in some plugin or theme files, but not when WP enviroment is still loading.

As I am not really sure if your intention is really correct, you have to use some other way (with PHP native functions) to distinct between front-end and administration. For example something like this:

```
if( strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/wp-admin/') !== FALSE ) {
  define('DB_NAME', 'wp_db');
} else { ... }
```

But I don't think it is bulletproof solution. Ajax call are processed in administration, `wp-login.php` is not covered by the code above, etc.

Answer (score -1):

Try to insert your code

```
if(is_admin()) {...}
```

AFTER

```
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
```

because function is_admin() is loaded while wp-setting.php is executed. In this way you could avoid the error message, but I cannot understand why have your site to work correctly only for administrator? It seems the semantic error. I think some components will not work correctly under administrator too.

Comment: there is an explicit comment in the code warning **against** inserting code there....